# How to duplicate save data to another Switch from an account without a Nintendo account?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-account

I have a Switch and I recently got another one, I have 2 accounts but only one has most of the saved data and it doesn't have a Nintendo account. I could only duplicate save data from my other account, with a Nintendo account. I want to keep the saved data on the original Switch while also using it on my new one but I don't know how, someone please help me.